# My program is not accepting simple string in c using getchar

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
int count0=0,count1=0,cnt=0;
    char str[200];             

    char ch;

   ch= getchar();
    while(ch!='\0')
    {
        str[cnt]=ch;
        cnt++;
    }
    str[cnt]='\0';
    printf("%s",str);
```

output expected :

```
shubham
```

**output:**

```
Your code didn't print anything.
```

**input:**

```
shubham
```

Comment: why did you not call `getchar()` in your loop ?

Comment: Probably, you can replace `while` with `do-while` and take this statement `ch= getchar();` inside `do-while`.

Comment: You are accepting only one character and your loop never stops.

Comment: Take a debugger, run your code line by line. That is the first step always. It will immediately show you what’s going wrong.

Comment: thanks! @babon You are right!!

Comment: What does `man getchar` tell you its **return** `type` is? (it's not `char`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just accepting one character, you should replace `while()` with `do-while()`.

```
int ch;
do
{
  ch= getchar();
  if(ch == EOF)
  {
      str[cnt] = '\0';
      break;
  }
  else
     str[cnt] = ch;
  cnt++;
}while(ch != '\0');
```

The above loop should fix the issue that you are facing. You need to enter NULL terminator using `ctrl`+`@` at the end of the string.

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`; `ch` should be declared as an `int` to ensure that it can hold the value of `EOF`. Further, if `EOF` is returned, it will be returned on subsequent calls to `getchar()`, leading to an infinite loop since this code does not check for `EOF`. This will lead to undefined behavior here, since `cnt` will continue to be incremented and an out-of-bounds access will soon follow.

Comment: @DavidBowling Made the changes in the answer. In the case `getchar()` returns `EOF` then a check needs to be done outside the loop on `ch` and if  `ch` is `EOF` then `str[]` needs to be terminated with `NULL` `str[cnt] = '\0'`.

Comment: You might now notice that if `EOF` is returned from `getchar()`, its value is stored in `str[]` (and `str[]` is then not null-terminated).

Comment: @Gaurav still your program is not helping
       
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch= getchar();
            str[cnt]=ch;
            cnt++;
        }while(ch!='\0' || ch!= EOF);
        str[cnt]='\0';
        printf("%s",str);

Comment: @SHUBHAMJANGAM Now, It should.

Comment: @Gaurav now its fully functional and can accept almost any character
thanks-you !!
DavidBowling
thanks!
we can accept getchar() in int or char .... both are ok
eg: char ch= getchar() // totally fine

Comment: @SHUBHAMJANGAM -- robust code _must_ store the return value from `getchar()` in an `int`, _not_ in a `char`. This is because `getchar()` can return `EOF`, which may not fit in a `char` type. Note that even if it is not expected that `EOF` will be an input value, `getchar()` also returns `EOF` in case of an error in the function; since we have no control over when errors may occur (though they may be rare), we must be prepared to handle them when they come.

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop is fine.  Simply put the `getchar()` in it.

Use `int ch` rather than `char ch` as `getchar()` typically returns 1 of *257* different values: 0 - 255 and `EOF`(a negative value).  `EOF` indicates end-of-file (or rare input error).

```
size_t count = 0; 
int ch;
// test to insure not too many read,        ch == EOF?   ch == end-of-line?  
//               |                             |                |
while (count < sizeof str - 1 && (ch == getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
  str[count++] = ch;
}
str[count] = '\0';
puts(str);
```

Or perhaps one prefers a `for()` loop?

```
size_t count; 
for (count = 0; count < sizeof str - 1; count++) {
  int ch == getchar();
  if (ch == EOF || ch ==  '\n') {
    break;
  }
  buf[count] = ch;
}
buf[count] = '\0';
puts(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0,T;       

    T=getchar();
    int ch;
    for(i=0; i<T ;i++)
    {
        int cnt=0;
        char str[200];
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        {
            str[cnt] = ch;
            cnt++;
        }
        str[cnt]='\0';
        printf("\n%s",str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**
here str is storing almost everything
space, \n, 
**
**expected output:**
     shubham
     shubh

**output:**
     shubham 
     shubh
     shubham
     shubh
**input:**
     shubham 
     shubh
*/

Comment: I just want to store one string from input text at a time and display it to console
but it is taking multiple strings

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",&T);`  --> `scanf("%d",&T);` Note that it is almost always wrong to use trailing whitespace characters in `scanf()` format strings. This causes `scanf()` to wait for a nonwhitespace character to be entered before returning, causing trouble with interactive input. Instead, to remove the newline character after `scanf()` use: `int ch; while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` Again, it is mandatory that `ch` be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @DavidBowling 
Now i have improved code
bt the problem  is this loop only take 2 text input and print them but not 3 rd one while value of T is 3  ::  I/O->
3   shubham###       ###mahbuhs     jshubham  ::  Expected O/P->
shubham###
###mahbuhs
jshubham  ....O/P->
shubham###
###mahbuhs

Comment: here getchar in while is eating white spaces present after T

but when i use getchar instead of scanf it is working fine

Comment: You have to remove the newline character from the input stream after the first call to `scanf()`. You can use the loop I mentioned in my last comment (place it immediately after the `scanf()` line), or you could just do `getchar()` here to remove the `\n` character. The loop is the canonical way to portably clear an input stream that contains at least a newline character.

Comment: fine. . .
Thanks!! :)